# Populate SELECT with OPTGROUP and OPTION values using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have got a simple bit of PHP / Ajax / jQuery working so that the contents of a 2nd SELECT are changed when I choose a value in the first SELECT.

**HTML**

```
<select class='form-control' id='cat_parent' name='cat_parent'>
    <option value=''>Select Parent</option>
    <option value='1'>Oracle</option>
    <option value='6'>SQL</option>
</select>

<select class='form-control' id='cat_id' name='cat_id'>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cat_parent').change(function() {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        // Populate Categories once select Parent
        $.get("../ajax/ajax-cats-from-parent.php", {'cat_parent': currentValue}, function(data) {
            var cat_id = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#cat_id').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < cat_id.length; i++) {
                var regionOption = '<option value="'+cat_id[i]['id']+'">';
                regionOption += cat_id[i]['label'];
                regionOption += '</option>';
                $('#cat_id').append(regionOption);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**PHP (ajax-cats-from-parent.php)**

```
 $sql = "SELECT cats.fld_label
              , cats.fld_id
           FROM tbl_b_cats cats
          WHERE cats.fld_parent = ? 
       ORDER BY cats.fld_label";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    throw new Exception("Error preparing statement: $stmt->error, SQL query: $sql");
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['cat_parent'])) {
    throw new Exception("Error binding parameter: $stmt->error");
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
} else {

    $AjaxCatsFromParent = array();

    $stmt->bind_result($fld_label, $fld_id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $AjaxCatsFromParent []= [
            'id'    => $fld_id,
            'label' => $fld_label
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($AjaxCatsFromParent);

}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

$conn -> close();
```

That all works fine.

I'm trying to populate another SELECT, also based on choosing a value in the first SELECT menu (ID cat_parent).

This is so that for a new post, I can assign a parent post.

The trouble I am having is that the SELECT has an OPTGROUP label for each category, and then within the OPTGROUP, posts are listed for that category.

The SQL to get the posts is:

```
$query = "SELECT fld_id fld_id2
               , fld_title fld_title2 
            FROM tbl_c_posts 
           WHERE fld_catid = ? 
        ORDER BY fld_title";
```

Where the ? is the ID of the category that the posts are assigned to.

I would want the SELECT to look like this for example:

```
<select class='form-control' id='parent_cat_id' name='parent_cat_id'>
    <option value=''>Select Parent Post</option>
    <optgroup label='Accounts Payable'>
            <option value='88'>a</option>
            <option value='1'>AP - Invoices</option>
            <option value='79'>AP - Supplier Reports</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label='Accounts Receivable'>
            <option value='2'>AR - Customers</option>
            <option value='3'>AR - Interface Lines</option>
            <option value='4'>AR - Transactions</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label='BLOB'>
            <option value='87'>s</option>
            <option value='86'>sadsadsad</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Therefore the problem I have is that the PHP needs to output:

1. A loop for the Categories (to output the OPTGROUP labels)
2. For each Category, a loop of Posts assigned to that Category (to output the OPTION values)

However, the PHP code can only output one array, as far as I know?

I got this far:

```
// SQL FOR THE OPTGROUP LABELS ############################################

 $sql = "SELECT cats.fld_label
              , cats.fld_id
           FROM tbl_b_cats cats
          WHERE cats.fld_parent = ?
       ORDER BY cats.fld_label";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    throw new Exception("Error preparing statement: $stmt->error, SQL query: $sql");
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['cat_parent'])) {
    throw new Exception("Error binding parameter: $stmt->error");
}

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
} else {

    // array for OPTGROUPS
    $AjaxOptGpLabel = array();

    $stmt->bind_result($fld_label, $fld_id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $AjaxOptGpLabel []= [
            'label' => $fld_label
        ];

        // sub-select for the posts assigned to the category
        $query = "SELECT fld_id fld_id2
                       , fld_title fld_title2 
                    FROM tbl_c_posts 
                   WHERE fld_catid = ? 
                ORDER BY fld_title";

        $stmt2 = $conn->stmt_init();

        if (!$stmt2->prepare($query)) {
            throw new Exception("Error preparing statement: $stmt2->error, SQL query: $query");
        }

        if (!$stmt2->bind_param('s', $fld_id)) {
            throw new Exception("Error binding parameter: $stmt2->error");
        }

        $stmt2->execute();
        $stmt2->store_result();

        if ($stmt2->num_rows > 0){

            // array for the posts
            $AjaxOptGpPosts = array();

            /* get results */
            $stmt2->bind_result($fld_id2, $fld_title2);

            while ($stmt2->fetch()) {

                $AjaxOptGpPosts []= [
                    'id'    => $fld_id2,
                    'label' => $fld_title2
                ];

            }

        }

        /* tidy up */
        $stmt2->free_result();
        $stmt2->close();

    }

    echo json_encode($AjaxOptGpLabel);

}
/* free and close */
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

$conn -> close();
```

So this sort of works in as much as the PHP generates a "AjaxOptGpPosts" array containing the posts for each Category, but then?

1. How do I get that into the output of the PHP, since it currently only returns the array for the OPTGROUPS via:

   echo json_encode($AjaxOptGpLabel);
2. How would I revise the jQuery to have a loop within a loop to populate the OPTGROUPS and OPTION elements?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the returned data format, share a sample of the value of `data`

Comment: That's part of the problem. I don't know how to change the PHP to get the data into a format where it contains all of the OPTGROUP headings with all of the post IDs and titles nested below that.

Comment: This is the format of the data returned for e.g. the categories which can be used for the OPTGROUP headings: [{"label":"AP"},{"label":"AR"},{"label":"EAM"},{"label":"GL"},{"label":"HR"},{"label":"INV"},{"label"
:"Other"},{"label":"PA"},{"label":"PO"},{"label":"SysAdmin"}]

Comment: But obviously it needs the post data below that?